# Algorithm to Compute Maximal Points in Pointset

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, poset

I had this as the final question on an algorithms final (now completed):

Given a set of (x,y) points **P**, let **M(P)** be the set of **[maximal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element) points** given the following partial ordering on P:

```
(x,y) < (x',y') if and only if x < x' and y < y'.
```

Thus:

```
M({(0,0),(1,1)})={(1,1)}
M({(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)})={(0,1),(1,0)}
```

Give algorithms that compute M(P) with time complexity O(nh), O(n log n), and O(n log h) (where n = |P| and h=|M(P)|)

My O(nh) algorithm:

```
Declare M as a set of points
foreach p in P:
  addP = true
  foreach m in M:
    if(p < m):
      addP = false
      break
    if(m < p):
      M.remove(m)
  if(addP)
    M.add(p) //doesn't add if M contains p
return M
```

My O(n log n) algorithm:

```
Declare M as a set of points
Sort P in reverse lexicographic order
maxY := -inf
foreach p in P:
  if(p.y > maxY):
    M.add(p)
    maxY = p.y
return M
```

**What is an  O(n log h) algorithm?**
My intuition is that it is a modification of the first algorithm, but using some clever data structure (perhaps a modification of a binary tree) that doesn't need to be scanned through for each point.

**Is there such an algorithm for a general [poset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)?**
This would find the leaves of any directed tree given a list of vertices and constant time lookup of whether there is a directed path between two given vertices.

Comment: you first algorithm doesn't work - the inner loop never executes, because M starts as empty

Comment: In addition to what @PetarIvanov wrote: the O(nh) solution is simply iterate over the entire set of points and add a point to the maximal set, until there is nothing more to add.

Comment: @PeterSmith: Ah, I misremembered it. Fixed now.

Comment: @amit: I'm not sure what you mean by "add a point to the maximal set"

Comment: @QuicksilverJohny: simple O(nh) solution: iterate over the entire set of points, and choose the maximal point, which was not previously chosen [can be done by marking points that were chosen], let it be `p`. If there is no such point - end the algorithm. else: add `p` to the maximal set, and repeat.

Answer (score 6):

That's a **really really evil** exam question (unless your instructor told you about one of the O(n log h) algorithms for convex hull, in which case it's merely **evil**).

The problem is called 2D MAXIMA and is the typically the domain of computational geometers because of its close relationship to computing convex hulls. I can't find a good description of a O(n log h) algorithm for the maxima problem, but [Timothy Chan's O(n log h) algorithm for 2D CONVEX HULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan's_algorithm) should give you the flavor.